# Evaluating $(\frac{\cos x}{1-\sin x})^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$(\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x})^2$

$f\;'(x)= 2(\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}) \times (\dfrac{-\sin x+\sin^2x-\cos^2x}{(1-\sin x)^2})$

Does $\sin^2x-\cos^2=1$? or $-1$?  Then it could factor with the bottom and the answer would be $\dfrac{2\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}$. Is this right?

Comment: You did wrong in doing the derivative. It will be $f\;'(x)= 2(\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}) \times (\dfrac{-\sin x+\sin^2x+\cos^2x}{(1-\sin x)^2})$ Now you can do it using $sin^2x+cos^2x=1$

Comment: @Rana OK, thanks +1, but isn't the derivative of $(1-\sin x)=-\cos x$? so wouldn't it be $-\cos^2 x$?

Comment: yes, but you have a negative sign in the formula already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x=1$,

$$f\;'(x)= 2(\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}) \times (\dfrac{-\sin x(1-\sin x)+\cos^2x}{(1-\sin x)^2})= 2(\dfrac{\cos x}{1-\sin x}) \times (\dfrac{1-\sin x}{(1-\sin x)^2})=\frac{2\cos x}{(1-\sin x)^2}.$$

Comment: OK, thanks +1, but isn't the derivative of $(1-\sin x)=-\cos x$? so wouldn't it be $-\cos^2 x$?

Comment: notice that: $(\frac{f}{g})'=\frac{f'g-fg'}{g^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)$ does not equal $-1$ or $1$.
$$\sin^2(x)+\cos^2(x)=1,$$

So $\sin^2(x)-\cos^2(x)$ is equal to:

$$\sin^2(x)-(1-\sin^2(x))= 2\sin^2(x)-1,$$ or alternatively,

$$1-\cos^2(x)-\cos^2(x)= 1-2\cos^2(x).$$

Comment: OK, thanks +1, but isn't the derivative of $(1-\sin x)=-\cos x$? so wouldn't it be $-\cos^2 x$?

Comment: Yes, the derivative of $(1-\sin x) = - \cos x$. I'm not sure what you're deriving to get $-\cos^2(x)$, though.